# How to implement WebSockets with microservices architecture

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, microservices

I'm learning microservices and I want some practice. So firstly I try to imagine architecture for chatting app. I did it:[image: microservices architecture]

But as you can see the most important part is not completed.

Generally, when SignalR gets new message will check if he has target connection and the user ids matches. If yes, then sends message to target immediately. Otherwise transmits message to RabbitMQ and then the message is send to all SignalR servers except this one which provided message (at least I think it could work like that, I'm learning microservices for a few hours).

But how can I communicate end user with SignalR server if there is API Gateway as middle man? What if I have many API Gateways (e.g. one for web and other for mobile devices), or after API Gateway there is load balancer? How can I have WebSocket between end-user and SignalR server in this situation? Is that even possible?

*I assume that only API Gateway is exposed to Internet. Maybe this assumption is bad while working with WebSockets?*

Comment: The question is unclear. `microservices architecture` is a marketing or fashion term, empty of meaning. Services are services. WebSockets is a network protocol that can be used by any kind of service, *if it's appropriate*. It's not the only one that allows two-way communications either. gRPC is better for service-to-service communications. WebSockets are used for server-to-browser push, because gRPC itself isn't supported by browsers and gRPC-Web has limitations, including no streaming support

Comment: As for the diagram itself, why do you want two independent SignalR servers? To solve which *real* problem? SignalR scaleout is already supported by [using a Redis backplane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-7.0#redis-backplane)  although there are other implementations too. API Gateway: Why do you want it and again, what *real* problem is it solving? If you have a few dozen internal clients you don't need a gateway.

Comment: Ocelot allows [SignalR and WebSockets proxying](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/websockets.html#signalr) but only a few features work with WebSockets: Load balancing, Routing and Service Discovery

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there a sample about how to use this Redis backplane? If I want send message to concrete user which may but also may not be connected to the same SignalR server, how can I publish event at Redis? Is it done automatically when I call default SignalR methods? And also subscribing for events is also autoamtically? I don't think I should call Redis directly from code, because what would be goal of using `AddStackExchangeRedis()`?

Comment: It's done automatically. The docs I linked to, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-7.0) explain how this works and how to configure SignalR to use Redis.

Comment: I have read it twice and still don't know where they say it's done automatically and how to setup my hub, basic methods like `OnConnectedAsync`. From which class shall my hub inherit? If it's done automatically, probably not from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`?

Comment: If you don't have the API gateway in your picture, then I will say [Azure Signalr Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview) solved all your requirements. Since I don't know about API gateway, so I can't answer that part.